# Is there any bitcoin exchange software that does not split net income?

Tags: exchanges

I'm going to create a bitcoin exchange service and I am trying to find a platform to do this. All the platforms I have found so far (bex.io and buttercoin), propose to split income with you. Is there any platform out there that sells or licenses without this revenue sharing model?